# jquery multiple and changing ids selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got a simple qiestion, i want to show and hide my divs according to their idies, but couldnt figure out, for example i have a different divs and inputs with different ids:

```
<input onfocus="showtip(1)" onblur="hidetip(1); />
<div id="tip1"></div>
<input onfocus="showtip(2)" onblur="hidetip(2); />
<div id="tip2"></div>
```

and

```
function showtip(id) {
    $('.tip[id]').show('slow');
}
function hidetip(id) {
    $('.tip[id]').hide('slow');
}
```

i can write it in javascript, to make it work, but i cant hide it with animation, thus i used jquery, but i can't define ids :( thank you all for the help! i really appreciate it!

Comment: To select by `id` use `#`: `$("#elementId").show();` - is that what you're asking?

Comment: Hiya, you are trying is `.class_name` try `#id_name` and please go to this site and read some basic http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean:

```
function showtip(id) {
    $('#'+tip).show('slow');
    //OR
    $('yourElement[id="'+tip+'"]').show('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the `id` attribute in jQuery use the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) :

```
$('#<yourid>').show('slow');
```

so your method would be :

```
function showtip(id) {
   $('#tip'+id).show('slow');
}
```

(Note: `ids` should be unique across the whole document so no need to include the `div` bit in the selector)

If you `id` attributes contained characters such as `.` which means other things (ie a class selector) then you can use the attribute equals selector :

```
$('[id="123.abc"]').show('slow')
```

Comment: yes :) u're mind reader o_0 i didnt finish qeuestion but u already answered it )) lol

Comment: sorry but @sudhir was first ) anyway +1

Comment: But what if your id attribute contains a `'` or `"` character? ;)

Comment: @Domenic then you need a good talking too !!! :-) Something I would never put in the `id` attribute ... would cause no end of problems

Answer (score 1):

@ManseUK's method is by far the most common. But it is technically incorrect, as for example it will fail for id's containing characters that have other meanings in CSS, like `.`. The most correct solution is:

```
function showTip(id) {
    $(document.getElementById(id)).show("slow");
}

// This will work:
<div id="abc.123"></div>
showTip("abc.123");
```

This solution is also very slightly faster, since internally that's what jQuery would translate `$("#" + id)` to (in the cases where it works).

How this works:

- `document.getElementById(id)` gets the raw DOM node.
- `$(...)` wraps a raw DOM node in a jQuery object, which has jQuery methods like `show`.

Comment: +1 for being technically correct :-) and updated my answer with an example of using the attribute equals selector